# Why wont my VBA string become case sensitive?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code that will open a spreadsheet, set a string of "TH" and then search a column for any cells that include "TH" and filter for them. Although, I want it to only search for cells that include "TH" capitalized.

```
Sub OpenAUMReport_and_Filter()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Spreadsheet.csv"


Dim strName As String
strName = ("TH")

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=*" & (strName) & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
Workbooks("Spreadsheet.csv").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.AutoFit
Workbooks("Spreadsheet.csv").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Right now it is including any "th" in its search and filtering for those as well. Is there any way I can make the string case sensitive so that it only searches for "TH" if it is capitalized. I have tried using `Ucase` but it hasn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/perform-a-case-sensitive-filter-in-excel/